# Ключевое слово в качестве имени поля объекта анонимного класса

Tags: c#

Мне необходимо создать поле с именем "params" в объекте анонимного класса. Обычным способом я этого делать не могу, т.к. "params" является ключевым словом. Как быть?

Comment: поставить перед именем  `@`

Comment: [What's the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/91817/2881286)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте префикс `@`. Реальное имя поля при этом будет без префикса:

```
var test = new { @params = "some" };
Console.WriteLine(test.GetType().GetProperty("params").Name); // params
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно префиксировать ключевое слово символом `@`. Подробнее [там](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/index)